# best way to write Spark Dataset[U]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Ok, so I am aware of the fact that `Dataset.as[U]` just changes the view of the Dataframe for *typed* operations.

As seen in this example:

```scala
case class One(one: Int)

val df = Seq(
    (1,2,3),
    (11,22,33),
    (111,222,333)
    ).toDF("one", "two", "thre")

val ds : Dataset[One] = df.as[One]

ds.show
```

prints

```
+----+----+-----+
| one| two|three|
+----+----+-----+
|   1|   2|    3|
|  11|  22|   33|
| 111| 222|  333|
+----+----+-----+
```

This is totally fine and works in my favor most of the times. BUT now I need to write that `ds` to disk, with only that column `one`.

To enforce the schema I could do
`.map(x => x)` as this is a typed operation, the case class schema will take effect. This operation also results in a `Dataset[One]`, but with the underlying data reduced to column `one`. This just seems awfully expensive looking at the execution plan

```
== Physical Plan ==
*SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line2012488405320.$read$$iw$$iw$One, true]).one AS one#9408]
+- *MapElements <function1>, obj#9407: $line2012488405320.$read$$iw$$iw$One
   +- *DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line2012488405320.$read$$iw$$iw$One), obj#9406: $line2012488405320.$read$$iw$$iw$One
      +- LocalTableScan [one#9391]
```

What are alternative implementations to achieve

```
ds.show
+----+
| one|
+----+
|   1|
|  11|
| 111|
+----+
```

**UPDATE 1**
I was thinking of a general solution to the problem. Maybe something along these lines?:

```scala
def caseClassAccessorNames[T <: Product](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = {
  typeOf[T]
    .members
    .collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.name
    }
    .map(m => m.toString)
}

def project[T <: Product](ds: Dataset[T])(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Dataset[T] = {
  import ds.sparkSession.implicits._

  val columnsOfT: Seq[Column] =
      caseClassAccessorNames
      .map(col)(scala.collection.breakOut)

  val t: DataFrame = ds.select(columnsOfT: _*)

  t.as[T]
}
```

I managed to get this working for the trivial example, but need to evaluate it further. I wonder if there are alternative, maybe built-in, ways to achieve something like this?

Comment: Kind of unclear what your real world use case is here, but why not `val ds = df.select('one).as[One]`?

Comment: Ah, yes that would work, of course. I was looking for a more general solution though. Will edit my question